# Watch multi-stream video file while being recorded by ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to record four 1080p video streams simultaneously and I would like to view these streams in real time while they are being recorded. Ideally I would like to view them from a separate machine, using some convenient Linux data sharing method like ssh/sshfs/..., but that is a nice-to-have. Is there a practical way to accomplish this?

The ffmpeg recording command that I currently use is like this:

```
ffmpeg \
  -f v4l2 -i $cam0 \
  -f v4l2 -i $cam1 \
  -f v4l2 -i $cam2 \
  -f v4l2 -i $cam3 \
  -f matroska \
  -map 0 \
  -map 1 \
  -map 2 \
  -map 3 \
  -c copy \
  $output.mkv
```

My problem would be solved if I could use a command like `ffplay` or `vlc` to play one or more of the video streams, always tracking close to the end of the stream, playing more as data becomes available. I haven't found such an option though.

One alternative might be to have the recording ffmpeg process also tile the four 1080p videos into one 4K grid and pipe that to ffplay. Then I could at least preview on the same machine that is recording. I have not been able to work out the right ffmpeg command to do the tiling though and would appreciate an example.

Comment: Not with MKV output.

Comment: How about with a different output then? I am even open to running multiple separate ffmpeg processes if that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with TS container output.

```
ffmpeg \
  -f v4l2 -i $cam0 \
  -f v4l2 -i $cam1 \
  -f v4l2 -i $cam2 \
  -f v4l2 -i $cam3 \
  -f mpegts \
  -map 0 \
  -map 1 \
  -map 2 \
  -map 3 \
  -c copy \
  $output.ts
```

and for monitoring,

```
ffmpeg -sseof -3 -i $output.ts -map 0:v:0 -f sdl2 -
```

This will attempt to seek to 3 seconds from the end of the file based on the recorded duration at the time ffmpeg parses the file, and display the first stream. Expect some delay before playback, as ffmpeg waits for a keyframe.

To combine all four streams, you would add stack filters, like xstack.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am slow with feedback because I am struggling a bit to make it work. First ffmpeg sdl output wouldn't play my video, which I fixed with '-pix_fmt yuv420p', and now the problem is that playback is too fast (>3x) and it quickly hits the end of file and errors. So I'm trying to force the sdl2 playback to run at 60fps like the input (a USB video capture card.)